# How to show a pop up if there is a change in freetextbox asp.net editor using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, freetextbox

Trying to show a pop up using jQuery on a submit/post action.

Using [freetextbox](http://www.freetextbox.com/) and not planning to change it.

In my aspx page, the following script is added to find if a change in content.

```
function checkForContentChanges(action) {
        debugger;
        var consentTextBox = "";
        if (FTB_API != undefined && FTB_API != null) {
            objFTBControl = FTB_API['ConsentFreeTextBox'];
            if (objFTBControl) {
                var consentTextBox = objFTBControl.GetHtml;
            }
        }else {
            consentTextBox = $('#ConsentFreeTextBox').html();
        }

        ////var consentTextBox = $('#ConsentFreeTextBox').html();
        var consentContent = $('#hdnConsentContent').val();
        if (consentTextBox != consentContent) {
            ShowErrorPopup(action);
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I have a hidden variable that stores the content on page load named "hdnConsentContent" for content comparison on post action

Its not working and showing my pop up.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think there is another issue associated with the same. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/740670/ie-freetext-box-is-rendered-as-text-area

Comment: The issue is partially resolved as the issue was with client ID of the control. But Hidden control is having html and ftb control is returning stripped text. Also the editor is rendered as text area in IE 11.